# Facebook sharing plugin is not working right and shows error page instead when shared

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-social-plugins

My Facebook sharing plugin does not work right for this blog post page at https://www.tradesumo.com/Home/LearningsFromLaunchingAStartupWhileAtUniversity at the bottom of the page under "Like our blog post? Share this with your friends!" When I try to share it, it loads up our error page (you will see lots of pandas) instead of the specified image and the right title and description.

I don't understand why this isn't working coz the code we used is pretty similar to what I used for https://www.tradesumo.com/Home/Blog where the FB social sharing icon is working fine, and propagating the right things from the meta tags of that view.

Just FYI, the following are the meta tags and code for the FB sharing plugin respectively, for the blog and the blog post:

BLOG:

```
@section AdditionalMeta
{
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="TradeSumo | Blog" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="~/Scripts/Landing/assets/img/custom/meta.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.tradesumo.com/Home/Blog" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Latest news, updates and events about TradeSumo." />   
}



<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.tradesumo.com/Home/Blog&t=TradeSumo%20|%20Blog" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="~/Scripts/Landing/assets/img/flat_web_icon_set/color/Facebook.png"></a></li>
```

BLOG POST:

```
@section AdditionalMeta
{
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="TradeSumo | Learnings From Launching A Startup While At University" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="~/Scripts/Landing/assets/img/blog/startupweekend1.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.tradesumo.com/Home/LearningsFromLaunchingAStartupWhileAtUniversity" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="People always ask me what launching a tech startup while studying or working is like. It is definitely possible as long as you have a committed team with a united vision." />   
}



<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.tradesumo.com/Home/LearningsFromLaunchingAStartupWhileAtUniversity&t=TradeSumo%20|%20Learnings%20From%20Launching%20A%20Startup%20While%20At%20University" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="~/Scripts/Landing/assets/img/flat_web_icon_set/color/Facebook.png"></a></li>
```

Would be great if someone could tell me why it is wrong.... I also tried debugging the plugin through the URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tradesumo.com%2FHome%2FLearningsFromLaunchingAStartupWhileAtUniversity but dunno what is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was with the image meta tag. It needs to have the full URL:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.tradesumo.com/Scripts/Landing/assets/img/blog/startupweekend1.jpg" />
```

rather than this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="~/Scripts/Landing/assets/img/blog/startupweekend1.jpg" />
```

Somehow the plugin cannot find the image and returns an error page coz of the image. It is weird that I have to treat the blog and blog post views differently for the image meta tag, coz I used the latter meta tag for the blog view and it works okay, and both the blog and the blog post views reside within the same Home Controller, so by right, they SHOULD work the same way. Anyway, problem fixed!